# ios - UITableViewCell programmatically or in IB?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, interface-builder

First of all, let me say that I am interested in performance for my tableview, as each cell is going to have quite a few pieces of data.

**What I am wondering is, is it a better idea to build my tableView cell programmatically or using Interface builder?  Are their pros and cons to each?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a lot of UILabels in a UITableViewCell, performance may be impacted.

Try putting together a cell in IB, make sure that the cell identifier in IB matches the cell identifier you are using in code to dequeue.

Also make sure that all labels are set to opaque, as that will help performance.

With all that done, use profiling with the CoreAnimation instrument on a device and try scrolling the table.  You'll get an FPS reading while you scroll - 20 FPS is a bit choppy but acceptable, much below that is really choppy.  A target would be 30FPS or higher.

If performance is not great, or if you must have transparent labels because of the background you are using, consider using a hybrid approach.  Design the cell in IB, but then instead of using that XIB file, use that in code as a template.

What that would mean is:

1) On cell creation, in layoutSubviews of the cell read one instance of the UITableViewCell from the xib into a static variable.

2) If you are targeting iOS 3.2 or later, for each label in the XIB create a CATextLayer at the same position with the same fonts as the label (CATextLayers will render faster).

3) If you are targeting 3.1 or later (do not target lower than 3.0 unless you are mad), inside a drawRect for the cell draw all of the text for your cell at the positions specified in the template label.

Generally though making the labels opaque will probably be good enough if you are reusing cells correctly (check to make sure they are being dequeued as you would expect).

Answer (score 4):

It's certainly easier to design and tweak your cell in IB. If there's any difference performance-wise, it's not likely to be noticeable so long as you reuse your cells as is recommended. If you're reusing cells, you'll only ever create a small handful of cells. You should absolutely do this no matter whether you're creating the cell programmatically or loading from a nib.

There are some things that are easier to accomplish in code than in IB, and there may be some things that you have to do in code. You'll know it when you run into one of these situations. Even so, you can always take a hybrid approach -- load your cell from a nib and then modify it programmatically as much as you like.

Comment: I like this approach.  Designing the cell in IB is SO much easier, so I will start with that, then change anything programmatically that I need to.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'd be better off building your cells programmatically. There isn't a lot of customization available through IB. Programmatically you can do a lot more. Those are about the pros and cons of each.